# How to get rid of the default .sortable animation

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jquery UI's .sortable for a site, and I'm wondering if I can alter/ get rid of the animation that is played when the element is dragged to the correct location.

jsFiddle displaying problem: http://jsfiddle.net/JohnFish/yCySq/

Answer (score 1):

The [`revert` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-revert) specifies that animation.
Just get rid of it.